# Using Tally for computed list of values

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm trying to use `Tally` to count the duplicated values in a list resulting from solving a linear system

```
list={{0.300823},{0.121771},{0.258845},{0.0518388},{0.0255293},{0.0440367},{0.238642},{0.106291},{0.258845},{0.0376355},{0.194645},{0.121771},{0.106291},{0.0557113},{0.0440367},{0.0129854},{0.0255293},{0.0518388},{0.0376355},{0.0557113}};

Tally[list]//MatrixForm
```

Here is what I got

[image]

It seems that `Tally` sees the extended values not the approximated ones.

Comment: Try `Tally[Flatten@list] // MatrixForm`  then it works  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nivmx.png)

Comment: Not sure what's happening but [**`this`**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXuYV.png) is what I get from the code. Perhaps you have some interfering definitions?

Comment: @Nasser It did not work!

Comment: @bmf I also get what your got without Flatten. I assumed OP is using older version?

Comment: @bmf the list is computed via LinearSolve !

Comment: What version are you using? It works for me using V 13.2 with or without Flatten.  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kx5DM.png)

Comment: @Nasser I'm working online !

Comment: It could be related then. I do not know. What is the output of $Version?

Comment: @Nasser probably version related, because you used Windows I am on macOS and we both have `13.2`. Perhaps the author of the OP can update with the version and we can take it from there or something

Comment: See the comment by @Nasser

Comment: @Nasser Trial version ;)

Comment: This is too chatty, lets clean the comments please. @A.PI you were asked for the output of `$Version` what is it? Please try to make an effort to explain, three words at the time is not enough to have a meaningful conversation. I think the issue is that the data in the OP's kernel has more significant digits than what we have on the question.  That would explain the difference.  Anyhow, the question is ill-defined unless we define what two numbers count as the same, so this should be something like `Tally[Round[list,0.001]]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that the data in the OP's kernel has more significant digits than what we have on the question, so for that kernel two numbers that in the question appear as identical are internally different.

Anyhow, the question is ill-defined unless we define what two numbers count as the same. So we necessarily need to coarse-grain the data or provide an explicit *test*.

Done in Wolfram Cloud, given that the OP commented to be working *"online"*.

```
$Version
(* 13.2.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2022) *)

list={
    {0.300823},{0.121771},{0.258845},{0.0518388},
    {0.0255293},{0.0440367},{0.238642},{0.106291},
    {0.258845},{0.0376355},{0.194645},{0.121771},
    {0.106291},{0.0557113},{0.0440367},{0.0129854},
    {0.0255293},{0.0518388},{0.0376355},{0.0557113}
};
```

Here I [`Round`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Round.html) to $0.001$.

```
Tally[Round[list,0.001]]//MatrixForm
```

[image]

Alternatively another sameness test needs to be defined in [`Tally`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tally.html)`[data, test]`

[image]

```
Tally[list,(Abs[First[#1-#2]]<1/1000)&]//TableForm
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you this exactly what I wanted to know.